# Why does this email not arrive?

Tags: linux, command-line, email

I have been attempting to send an email from the command line to myself, but the message does not appear in my inbox (or in spam or anywhere else). Below is the command I used, and a copy of the log. Please can anyone tell me where it is going wrong and what I can do about it.

I have exhaustively searched the web and tried many ideas, but this is the nearest I have got.

```
root@localhost]/home/Harry# tail -f /var/log/maillog &
...
[root@localhost]/home/Harry# mail -s "Test Mail" xxxx@btinternet.com
Hello
EOT
[root@localhost]/home/Harry# Jun 17 15:37:41 localhost sendmail[5043]: u5HEbf9U005043: from=Harry, size=227, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201606171437.u5HEbf9U005043@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
Jun 17 15:37:41 localhost sendmail[5044]: u5HEbf9c005044: from=<Harry@localhost.localdomain>, size=504, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201606171437.u5HEbf9U005043@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jun 17 15:37:41 localhost sendmail[5043]: u5HEbf9U005043: to=xxxx@btinternet.com, ctladdr=Harry (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30227, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u5HEbf9c005044 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun 17 15:37:42 localhost sendmail[5046]: u5HEbf9c005044: to=<xxxx@btinternet.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120504, relay=mx.bt.lon5.cpcloud.co.uk. [65.20.0.49], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jun 17 15:37:42 localhost sendmail[5046]: u5HEbf9c005044: to=<Harry@localhost.localdomain>, delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=120504, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jun 17 15:37:42 localhost sendmail[5046]: u5HEbf9c005044: u5HEbg9c005046: postmaster notify: User unknown
Jun 17 15:37:42 localhost sendmail[5046]: u5HEbg9c005046: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31733, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

---

Added in response to answer by @Curtis: Perhaps I should have said that the username in the original command line *was* a correct user, the one I use all the time, so why would btinternet.com not recognise it?

Answer (score 1):

The mail server at btinternet.com says that the user does not exist. See your log file:

```
u5HEbg9c005046: postmaster notify: User unknown
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it misses the second part "What can I do about it?"